# Spring MVC latest Form Controler

Tags: spring-mvc

```
public class OrganizationFormController extends SimpleFormController {

    protected final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public OrganizationFormController() {
        setCommandClass(Organization.class);
        setCommandName("organizationForm");
```

Can anybody help me to know which "formcontroller" latest in "SpringMVC.."
currently I am using "SimpleFormController,"
And I was reading few point About "MultiControllerAction.."
So please can you help me...

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: Minor cleanup.  Is your question really which "formcontroller" was most **recently added** in SpringMVC?  A better question might be to describe your intended use and ask which one is most **appropriate** to that use....

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just annotate your class with `@Controller`?  What do you need to do?